# How "with" keyword works in agda ?? and also the code below ??

Tags: agda

I am not able to understand it clearly. I tried to learn "with" keyword but there also i have doubt. Please help !!!

I wanted to understand the working of "with" and working of this code.

```
something-even : ∀ n → Even n ⊎ Even (suc n)
something-even zero = inj₁ zero
something-even (suc n) with something-even n
... | inj₁ x = inj₂ (suc-suc x)
... | inj₂ y = inj₁ y
(this states that either n is even or its successor is even). In fact, thm0 can be implemented without using recursion!

thm0 : ∀ x → ∃ λ y → Even y × x less-than y
thm0 n with something-even n
... | inj₁ x = suc (suc n) , suc-suc x , suc ref
... | inj₂ y = suc n , y , ref
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are familiar with Haskell, you will notice that in Agda there are no `if`-statements and no `case`.

`with` does pattern-matching of the expression result. For example, `with something-even n` evaluates `something-even n`, and then pattern-matches on the following lines with `... | inj₁ x` and `... | inj₂ y`. These match the expression, to see if its value is constructed using `inj₁` or `inj₂` constructor, so that the value wrapped by them can be used in the right-hand-side expressions: `suc (suc n) , suc-suc x , suc ref` uses `x` determined by `inj₁ x`, and `suc n , y , ref` uses `y` determined by `inj₂ y`

The actual constructor names come from the definition of `⊎` - see the type of `something-even` joins types `Even n` and `Even (suc n)`. So `x` in `inj₁ x` corresponds to a value of type `Even n` for given `n`, and `y` in `inj₂ y` corresponds to a value of type `Even (suc n)` for the same `n`.

Comment: `if_then_else_` is defined in `Data.Bool`. Agda has pattern-matching lambdas, and besides the usual `case_of_`, there is also dependent `case_return_of_` in `Function`. You can find examples [here](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/README/Case.agda). Moreover, it's better to use case-expressions instead of `with` whenever possible because of efficiency reasons.

Comment: @user3237465 I agree. Yet, I only needed to explain the meaning of `with`. Agda doesn't define `case..of` as key words, so even though you are right, I don't think I am wrong :-). Also, would be great if you could elaborate on the efficiency of `case_of_` compared to `with`. I'd expect they were done in the same way.

Comment: `with` generates an auxiliary function as described in the [wiki](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.With-expression). Have a look at [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.agda/5621) thread for a dramatic example.

Comment: @user3237465 hmm, but pattern-matching lambda also does... ok, I'll read that thread

Comment: @ajayv you could also upvote or accept the answer then